# Writing Laplace equation in polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I'm just beginning to study Diff Geom, in an introductory chapter I've stumbled upon a problem of expressing laplace equation in polar coordinates. I've found the solution of this problem and at one point in the solution second partial derivative of V by X is calculated. I do not understand why the way they calculate it is correct.

[image]

P.S. I understand how the 1st member is calculated, but not the other members.

Comment: The book doesn't do this derivation? What an odd book. In this case, I think including the image is fine, btw. Thanks for acknowledging that we prefer it to be typed, though. :)

Comment: The original book doesn't have a solution. The solution is from lecture notes I've found.

Comment: Well, this isn't really my area, but I'd be amazed if this wasn't in most books on the subject.

Comment: @Moo If you simply multiply the expressions in parenthesis, you will not get the final result. I've tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: It's one differential operator acting on another: you have by the product rule $ \partial_t (f(t) \partial_t) = f'(t) \partial_t + f(t) \partial_t^2 $.

Comment: @Chappers It looks you are right. I'll check it out. Thanks.